# uwp - How to make ContentDialog size according to contents?

Tags: dialog, uwp, size

In my `ContentDialog`, I have a `StackPanel` with about three controls (vertical orientation). My problem is that the ContentDialog's height stretches all the way to the bottom of the window even though its contents don't even occupy half of it.

I'm having a guess that this could be the `StackPanel`'s issue, but nevertheless how do I fix this?

I could set a `MaxHeight`, but I have to fill it with fixed values that differ per `ContentDialog`...

**UPDATE**

This is in MainPage.xaml (default starting page of VS UWP template). XAML shows only the creation of one use-case button, with this on the `Click` event:

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataEntryDialog dialog = new DataEntryDialog();

        //Show dialog
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
```

DataEntryDialog.xaml:

```
<ContentDialog
    x:Class="App1.Dialogs.UserAccountDataEntryDialog"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="TITLE"
    PrimaryButtonText="Save"
    SecondaryButtonText="Cancel"
    Loaded="ContentDialog_Loaded"
    PrimaryButtonClick="ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick">

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Header="Username" Margin="0,20,0,0"/>
        <PasswordBox Header="Password" Margin="0,12,0,0"/>
        <CheckBox Content="Active" Margin="0,12,0,0"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ContentDialog>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that's the default behavior of `ContentDialog`. If you resize your UWP app window, you'll see it stretch vertically and horizontally depending on the size of the window. My guess, this is done on purpose so your app's dialogs are supported on all platforms (desktop, mobile, tablet, xbox, etc...)

Comment: Thanks, but still not the desired result :( I have a `Button` in the main page (MainPage.xaml) which is supposed to show this `ContentDialog`.

Comment: Can you update the code to include the button and whatever surrounds the `ContentDialog`?